# How to select a custom composite type with PostgreSQL and JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

How do you select a composite type from PostgreSQL and JDBC? The only answers I'm finding suggest you have to parse the string value. I'm surprised it's that bad.

```
create type person as (age int, name text);
create table test (id int, p person);
insert into test values (1, ROW(45, 'Joe'));
```

And in Java...

```
var ps = pgConn.prepareStatement("select * from test")
var rs = ps.executeQuery()
rs.next()
// PGobject here is not part of JDBC, but specific to the PG driver.
var p = (PGobject)rs.getObject(2)
// p.value is "(45,Joe)"
```

That particular value isn't hard to parse obviously, but what about nested single and double quotes, commas, timestamps, etc. I expected something sane like a way to get the individual fields:

```
p.getInt(1)
p.getString(2)
```

It's worse if you have an array, eg: `person[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `select * from test`, do `select p.age, p.name from test`. Then you get each member as a separate column that JDBC can treat normally.